# Getting HTTP error 500.19 -Internal server where application pointing to wrong web.config location

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am facing issue in Asp.net mvc 5 application. Whenever I am executing the application, it is causing an HTTP Error 500.19 and detail error description its showing

> Cannot read configuration file

But the configuration file which it is showing is not correct. The location shown is already deleted by me.

Why it is still pointing to previous deleted location.

Comment: how r u running your application, iis express, local iis server or deployed to some server?

Comment: I m running this using IIS express

Comment: I am just trying to debug the application.

Comment: you deleted the location from what? IIS convention is that there is a web.config in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Go to projects properties -web and then under servers click on Create Virtual Directory and try running it
- Clean the solution, rebuild it and re run it

Comment: I am executing this project in visual studio.. Do I still need to create virtual directory ?

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.